# How to override website_sale_wishlist.js in V11?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, overriding, odoo

I want to override "update_wishlist_view" function which is defined under website_sale_wishlist module. Here is the function:

```
   update_wishlist_view: function() {
        if (this.wishlist_product_ids.length > 0) {
            $('#my_wish').show();
            $('.my_wish_quantity').text(this.wishlist_product_ids.length);
        }
        else {
            $('#my_wish').hide();
        }
    }
```

How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
odoo.define('website_sale_wishlist_extension', function (require) {
    "use strict";

    var ProductWishlist = require('website_sale_wishlist.wishlist');

    ProductWishlist.include({
        update_wishlist_view: function() {
            // execute your code after super call if apply
            this._super.apply(this, arguments);
            // execute your code before super call if apply
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I had already tried in this way, but it's not working. It gives error: Some modules could not be started.